# Get the higher result(s) from a questionnaire with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to build a questionnaire / personality test with jQuery.
I have an object in the end :

```
results = {
quality1 : 2,
quality2 : 3,
quality3 : 0,
quality4 : 3,
etc
}
```

I then want to retrieve the key with the higher value. No problem if there is only one matching result :

```
    topScore = 0;
    $.each(results, function(i,val) {
    if ( results[i] > topScore ) {
        topScore = results[i];
        topQuality = i;
    }
});
    console.log('Higher quality : ' + topQuality)
```

but what if there are many ? (for instance, in the example, quality2 and quality4)

I'm kind of lost, here...

Comment: The question is : "What would you want to do with many?" . Show every instance ? Then use a table where you put the top scores and empty it if a new top is found.

Comment: I need to build a query string : ?quality2=1&quality4=1&etc.

Comment: What values can 'quality' have?  Tell the range.  '0 <= quality <= 3'? Are all integers?

Comment: There are 8 questions with 5 options (quality) each. So a quality can have a value between 0 and 8 (all integers, yes) and a maximum of 4 equal qualities with a value of 2.

Comment: Why don't you simply send everything to the server (classic form) and do the treatment there ?

Comment: Well, i don't have access to the server side and this is for me, really, an exercice in javascript/jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
topScore = 0;
var topQualityIndexes = [];
$.each(results, function(i,val) {
   if ( results[i] > topScore ) {
    topScore = results[i];
    topQualityIndexes = [i];     
   }else if( results[i] == topScore ){
    topQualityIndexes.push(i);
   }
});
//Printing 
console.log( 'Higher qualities: ' + topQualityIndexes.join(",") );
```

Comment: thank you very much, and looking forward to not seeing that kind of question as a huge problem. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use a list and display all the highest values.

Comment: Displaying the results is not a problem, but displaying only the highest is a bit more tricky - for me.