# Dynamically add keys to jquery object

Tags: jquery, object

I have some working code and eventually end up with multiple returned values. Something like this:

```
console.log(variableName)
-- var1, var2, var1, var3 etc
```

How do I write a function to get all those variables that are logged from the variable into an object like this? (Fore every repeat the keys must be incremented/counted).

```
var obj {
  var1 : 2
  var2 : 1
  var3 : 1
  var4 : 0
}
```

Comment: You need to give us more information. What does "variableName" look like, what does it contain. Where is this data coming from? Is it an array? JSON? Something else?

Comment: [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) it onto an array, instead of using an object.

Comment: var1, var2 etc are just strings declared as variables. The variables are used in arrays in order to return those correct vars (strings). I just need to get those variables into an object and count each one. If it helps, full code is on http://jsfiddle.net/stereofx/ZjnVD/ as it's probably a bit too much to post here.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is work out how this guy got to his results object in this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818681/get-the-higher-results-from-a-questionnaire-with-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your `variableName` var is an array like such :

```
var variableName = ['var1', 'var2', 'var1', 'var3'];
```

In which case you could do this :

```
var obj = {};
$(variableName).each(function() {
    if (this in obj) {
        obj[this]++;
    } else {
        obj[this] = 1;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Arthur, I think I'm 1 step closer now.